# How to count HTML tags with R/Python

Tags: python, html, r, count, tags

[SOLVED]

I'm looking for a way to count the tags number of a HTML page using R or Python (preference R).

Given the following HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Conteúdo -->
</body>
</html>
```

The output can be any object containing the number of tags (vector, table, list, etc.). Before that, I also need to know how to read the HTML page in the R(python) in a way that makes it easier to count.

Thanks :)

Comment: Try `lxml` python package

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Particularly, see [On-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to start. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial services.

Comment: I'll start with the obligatory "what have you tried that didn't work?" comment.

Comment: Now, are you trying to count the tags in the _actual source document verbatim_ or the tags in the _mostly standards compliant_ document that will get created via reading in with most any C[++]-based XML library that Python and R both provide wrappers for? This is more important than you may expect. These parsers — in HTML mode — add in things. For proof, Do a "View Source" and compare side by side to the "Inspect Element" view in any browser. They do similar (but usually more) things. In XML mode, these parsers may not be able to actually parse the documents.

Comment: I wanted to tell from the original document. But the R functions I was using were messing things up. I discovered the beautifulSoup library of python and with it apparently this work will be much easier!

Comment: I think you just said things that don't make sense and you really don't seem to be in a position to be making definitive statements about what components of which language/tool are better for one situation or not. That will only serve to confuse other new coders looking for help.

Answer (score -1):

**[Problem Solved]** I created the following code in Python. With him I was able to, given a directory containing HTML files, return a nested list containing the name of the page and the number of tags of each type it contains:

```
class ContaTags:


def __init__(self, path):
    self.path = path
    self.arquivos = []
    self.tags = []
    self.Lista = []
    count = []


def run(self):
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from html.parser import HTMLParser

    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            count.append(tag)

        def handle_endtag(self, tag):
            count.append(tag)

    import os

    parser = MyHTMLParser()

    for file in os.listdir(self.path):
        if file.endswith(".html"):
            self.arquivos.append(file)

            caminho = (self.path + "\\" + file)

            doc = open(caminho, "r", encoding = "utf8")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')

            count = []
            parser.feed(soup.prettify())

            self.tags.append(count)


    from collections import Counter

    z = []

    for i, item in enumerate(self.tags):
        z.append(Counter(self.tags[i]))

    self.Lista = list(zip(self.arquivos, z))

    return self.Lista
```

Calling the class:

```
Sample = ContaTags("... Directory of Files...")
Sample.run()
```